Dash callback adjust dataframe elements
Context
I have two dataframes

dataframe1 is the input for a bar graph. This dataframe has columns such as 'opacity' and 'bg_color', which are used for styling individual bars related to a certain row. This is wrapped inside a definition.
dataframe2 is input for a seperate table, which is displayed in the dashboard (dash_table.DataTable). This table is created by a definition. It contains a drop down menu inside one of it's columns in the dashboard.

My goal
The combination of two columns in dataframe2 can be traced back to a row in dataframe1. Upon selecting yes for the drop-down menu in 'drop-down-column', I want to do the following;

Get the row for which 'yes' was selected*
Get the value for columns 'Aaa', 'Bbb'*
Get the associated row from dataframe1
Update elements such as opacity and color inplace
Refresh/update dashboard such that bar graph reflects new colors on new data of dataframe1*


are the pieces I cannot figure out.

Discussion such as this one did not yield the desired result.
Any pointers are welcome!
